# Calendar Access using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, office365api

We have an application for the user to book/Edit/Cancel Room mailbox meeting from the portal.

So the user should be able to create a calendar event in the room mailbox and all participants should receive the meeting invite

Could you please advise What permission is required on Graph API other than "Calendars.ReadWrite"

Comment: According to the [public document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) there is no other permission to create an event other than Calendar.ReadWrite.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-online-meetings?tabs=http#create-and-enable-a-meeting-online) about creating an online meeting, I tried to call the api and it worked with Calendars.ReadWrite permission, here's the detail.

1. Creating an Azure Ad app and add api permission
   [image]
2. Get the `access token` , please note I just set ReadWrite as scope.
   [image]
3. Call the api according to the document above and will get success response, you can open outlook and find meeting has created in calendar.
   [image]

And here is my url and parameter:

```
Post:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
Authorization:Bearer <access token>
Prefer：outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
Content-Type：application/json
body：{
  "subject": "Prep for customer meeting",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does this time work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-11-20T13:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-11-20T14:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "location":{
    "displayName":"Cordova conference room"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"AdeleV@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Adele Vance"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
  "isOnlineMeeting": true,
  "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}
```

Comment: Thank you TInywa,
Did you check whether all attendees received the meeting invite?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add some other mailbox address to the parameter and attendees all received the invitation except those have no calendar feature.

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

Seems you are sending a meeting invite from your calendar. In my case, I am not passing user credentail. Will i be able to create event in anyone's calendar?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I tried to use the api but I can't create event in someone else's calendar when I changed the url as 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events'. On the other hand, if using my way above, the attendees will also have notification in their calendar. Maybe you are puzzled about attendees can't bypass the lobby, I'm studying this case now, and I suggest to set the meeting configuration in the metion email or modify Microsoft teams admin center to let everyone can bypass lobby.